# Having scanf in C return void instead of int

Tags: c

If I have a program that is using scanf to get user inputted data:

```
    scanf("%d",&val);
```

When I run it through lint I get warnings saying that scanf returns a int and it is not being assigned anywhere. What is the c practice to solve this problem?  Do I type cast it as void?

```
    (void)scanf("%d",&val);
```

Comment: That's a fine approach.  It would be better if you verified that the result is `1` (or appropriate value).

Comment: @Jeff, agreed.  Much better to do `if (1 == scanf("%d", &val))` as it alerts the brain to modify both the comparison and the string at the same time.

Comment: The amount of harm inflicted due to using `lint` in the form of ugly casts to `void` and other code uglification is likely much greater than any benefit it ever provided. Just use your compiler's warnings, which are probably much more reasonable. If you want further static analysis, `clang` can do a much better job than `lint`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C best practice to solve this warnings is simple: Check the resultcode. The scanf function returns in the int if the operation has gone ok or not, and stores the error usually in errno.

The lack of resultcode checks usually results in big errors in certain situations.

Comment: The C best practice is to avoid `scanf` due to numerous problems making it robust.

Answer (score 2):

The proper answer, of course, is to not ignore the return value. For a robust program, you should always (EDIT: usually) check that the return value indicates success, and fail gracefully when it does not.

Comment: There are plenty of operations which either cannot fail, or for which there's no way to fail gracefully. One example would be unlocking a mutex after performing an operation on the state it protects. The "always check for failure" mantra doesn't really work; to be usable, certain functions must guarantee they won't fail, and for those, there's no need to check return values.

Comment: @R.., that's true, I shouldn't have said "always", but scanf is definitely not one of those functions.

Comment: If you're using `%n` to measure the amount read, you can know success/failure without checking the return value. In some cases this can be a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would do something like

```
int scanVal = scanf("%d", &val);
if (scanVal != 1) {
  // wait a minute, scanf couldn't match input to a "%d"!
}
```

and then act on the output in a sensible manner.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of silencing the lint message, just check the return value to make sure nothing has gone wrong. From the man page:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> These  functions  return  the number of input items
> successfully matched and assigned, which can be
> fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early
> matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before
> either the first successful conversion  or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is also  >returned if a read error occurs, in which case the
> error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and
> errno is set indicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. Compare its return value to the number you expect in order to detect errors.

```
while (scanf("%d",&val) != 1)
    printf("Try again.\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#pragma warning(disable:<warning number>)
scanf("%d",&val);
#pragma warning(default:<warning number>)
```

And your compiler will suppress that warning.

Comment: Only if your compiler supports that particular `#pragma`.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to assign the return value of scanf to see if all (or how many) items were read. In this particular case, if it returns anything but 1, something went wrong (e. g. you wanted a number but the user is giving you unprintable characters) and you should handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be robust in the presence of bad input, don't use `scanf("%d", ...)`.

For most errors, `scanf("%d", &val)` will return 0 to indicate that it wasn't able to read an int value (for example, if the input is "foo" rather than "123").

But if the input is syntactically valid but out of range (for example `9999999999999999999`), the behavior is *undefined*.

Most implementations will probably behave sanely, but I don't know how much consistency there is.

To read an int value safely, use `fgets()` (*not* `gets()`) followed by `strtol()`.  (`fgets()` can have problems with very long input lines, but there are ways to deal with that.)